# Lebesgue integral of a measurable function squeezed between two integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions

Suppose $f \leq g\leq h $ where both $f $ and $h$ are integrable over $E$ and $g$ is measurable in E. Is monotonicity enough to show that $g $ is also integrable?

I was thinking of

1. Integral comparison test which says that if g  is dominated by a nonnegative integrable function h  then g  is integrable. However this test requires g  to be of finite measure which is not in the hypothesis. But is the finiteness of g  implied by its being bounded below (f ) and above (h ) by integrable functions?
   I know that the test also requires h  to be nonnegative but since h  is integrable iff int |h| is integrable and hleq |h| then g  must really be dominated by  nonnegative integrable function (|hl )
   Is my logic correct?
2. I  am also thinking of using the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem. Can i just assume to have a sequence of measurable functions $g_n $ converging pointwise to $g $ so that i can have the $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} {\int g_n} = \int g $?

Comment: It is long ago that I learned this stuff, but can't you argue that $g-f$ is measurable and $0 \le g-f \le h-f$ ? Then $g-f$ is integrable and therefore $g = (g-f) +f $ is integrable. – And you probably meant *"both f and **h** are integrable"* in the first sentence of your question.

Comment: Yep it's $f $ and $h $. Made the necessary corrections. Thanks

Comment: How would it follow that $g-f $ is integrable? Sorry i am pretty lost. The blurry part is how does it follow immediately since it is still a need to show that $g $ is integrable?

Answer (score 1):

Decompose the functions into positive and negative parts respectively
$f= f_+ + f_-$, $h=h_+ + h_-$. Now see that $$|g| \leq \max(|f_-|, |h_+|).$$
From integrability of $f$ and $h$, the right hand side is finite, so $g$ is integrable.

To dispel any doubts about the fact that for measurable function $\phi$ such that $0\leq \phi \leq \psi$ for some integrable function $\psi$ implies the integrability of $\phi$, here is a short argument:

Assume that $\phi$ is measurable. Writing down the definition of Lebesgue integral for $\phi$ we bound it pointwise by $\psi$. The construction of Lebesgue integral is such that it is a monotone increasing sequence with respect to partitions of the domain, which by the above argument we have just bounded. Bounded increasing sequence has a finite limit which proves the integrability of $\phi$.

Comment: Thanks. So you're using this fact: Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions such that $0\le f \le g$ and $\int g \lt \infty$. Then we have $\int f \lt \infty$. How this fact can be proved?

Comment: If $f \leq g$ then $\int f \leq \int g$.

Comment: I think there is a subtlety here. We know that $g$ is integrable and $0\le f \le g$ but we don't want to assume that $f$ is integrable as well. In fact we are trying to show that $\int f$ exists. I'm looking for a proof of this fact and by combining it with your answer the proof is complete.

Comment: You assume that $f$ is measurable. Now you can write down the very definition of lebesgue integral for $f$ and bound it pointwise by $g$. The construction of Lebesgue integral is such that it is a monotone increasing sequence with respect to partitions of the domain, which by the above argument we have just bounded, therefore this sequence has a finite limit.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I think it would be nice if you add the proof to your answer, if you like. After the time limit is passed, I will award the bounty.